# Set active class to "home" button on navbar when url is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using this script for my dynamic navbar to set active class. What I want is to set the "home" button to active when you just visit the website and don't have the "index.php" in the url. Is this maybe easier with php?

```
/*menu handler*/
$(function(){
  function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
    if(str.substr(-1) == '/') {
      return str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
    }
    return str;
  }

  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var activePage = stripTrailingSlash(url);

  $('nav ul li a').each(function(){
    var currentPage = stripTrailingSlash($(this).attr('href'));

    if (activePage == currentPage) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: try `var currentPage = stripTrailingSlash($(this).attr('href')) || "index.php";` which replaces an empty path (`"/"` without the trailing slash) with `index.php` so that your href compare works. yes, php might be simpler, and it would work from pageload and w/o JS...

Comment: That did not work. Take a look for yourself: https://mkhosting.kohlercoding.dk/

Comment: oops, make it: `var activePage = stripTrailingSlash(url) || "/index.php";`, i had the default in the wrong slot... tested.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it answered?